# find last value from comma separated column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a comma separated text in a given column. Is there any way to get the last, second last and third last value?

```
select mnumber from mytable limit 2;

x, y, z, 1, 2, 3
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 7, 8, 9
```

The values returned from this column should look something like this...

```
col3, col2 col1
1 2 3
7 8 9
```

This does not work though:

```
split_part(mnumber,',',-1) as last_col
```

It would have returned what I need if minus values were allowed in split_part function.

Answer (score 14):

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse(message), ',', 3)) as third_last , 
reverse(split_part(reverse(message), ',', 2)) as second_last ,
reverse(split_part(reverse(message), ',', 1)) as my_last ,
message from my_table
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the other because it works for split parts of variable length.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you last value for the column

```
select SPLIT_PART(mnumber, ',', (len(mnumber)/2+1)) from mytable
```

this will give third last value for the column

```
select SPLIT_PART(mnumber, ',', ((len(mnumber)/2)-1)) from mytable
```

This will give second last value for the  column

```
select SPLIT_PART(mnumber, ',', (len(mnumber)/2)) from mytable
```